# iptables string match accept connection

Tags: string, matching, iptables

I have a question with iptables and string matching.  Most of what I have read drops packets that match a rule. When I use this, iptables will drop any connection with the string "test"

```
iptables -A INPUT  -p tcp --dport 80 -m string --string ! "test" --algo bm -j LOG --log-prefix ' INPUT TCP--- ' --log-level 4
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m string --string ! "test" --algo bm  -j DROP
```

So when I go to http://www.abc.com/?test, the connection will not go through.

What I want to do is the reverse, can I use string matching to approve a connection?

```
iptables -A INPUT  -p tcp --dport 80 -m string --string  "test" --algo bm -j LOG --log-prefix ' INPUT TCP--- ' --log-level 4
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m string --string  "test" --algo bm  -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j DROP
```

I want to only allow connections to port 80 that have the word test in it, somthing like this... http://www.abc.com/?test

Can this be done?

Thank you for the assistance,
golgiapparatus

Answer (score 0):

They right way to do something like that is to use a proxy. There is a way to do it with iptables, but definitely not the best solution.

You can't allow connections with a specified string because the data will appear after the connection is established. So you have to enable all the packets for the TCP handshake and then you have to allow packets with the string. With this solution, you have going to have a big list of broken connections :)

Comment: Can you explain how to setup a proxy to do this?

Comment: using Squid: 
acl blocktest url_regex test
http_access deny blocktest

Comment: I recommend to open a new question :)